# Action_up not working

Tags: android

I am working on a project in which I need to perform different functions on image press and image release. The following is my code. the action_down part works but the action up part doesn't what should i do.

plz help.

```
img2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility") @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//           rName = et.getText().toString();

                  switch(event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    AppLog.logString("Start Recording");
//                  startRecording();
                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    AppLog.logString("stop Recording");
//                  stopRecording();
                    dial();
                    break;
                  }





             return false;
         }
     });
```

Comment: when i see the log i only see start recording not stop recording.

Comment: What do you mean by `action up part doesn't work`? Th event is not triggered?

Comment: Once you return `false` from `onTouch()`, that View will stop receiving touch events until `ACTION_DOWN` happens again.

Comment: change  return false; to  return true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility") @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//           rName = et.getText().toString();

              switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                AppLog.logString("Start Recording");
//                  startRecording();
                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                AppLog.logString("stop Recording");
//                  stopRecording();
                dial();
                break;
              }





         return true;
     }
 });
```

change the
    `return false;`
to
    `return true;`